# Postgresql 42P17 error

Tags: postgresql

I've an error in Postgres that I don't understand.

The SQL state is 42P17 (it means "invalid object definition").

The error is

> SELECT rule's target list has too many entries

Can anybody explain to me more precisely how to get this error in order to resolve it?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query (or code) that produces the error (do **not** put code into comments)

Comment: I can't post my query here, but i just want to know when this error can happen. The number of columns in a result table is limited in postgresql ? I don't see the link between the SQL state and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error is *only* thrown if you try to create an `ON SELECT ... DO INSTEAD` rule on a table that has a select list longer than the list of columns on the table:

```
CREATE TABLE lord(id integer NOT NULL, val text NOT NULL);

CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO lord DO INSTEAD
   SELECT 1 AS id, 'value' AS val, 42 AS extra;

ERROR:  SELECT rule's target list has too many entries
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I just create directly a view instead of the table and the rule. It works fine!